# explanation for C program (uses comma operator)

Tags: c, comma-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i=0;
    while(i<4,5){
        printf("loop");
        i++;
    }
}
```

This code goes infinite loop. can anyone explain logic behind these?

Answer (score 0):

In the code

```
 while(i<4,5)
```

is same as

```
 while(5)
```

which is always true.

As per the comma operator properties, quoting from `C11`, chapter 6.5.17/P2

> *The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value*

Point to note: With this code, you'll hit [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to signed overflow in `i++`.